# Webpack installation - es6

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I am an es6 newbie! 
When all webpack installation were done, I started trying to create some files as in the pic

[image]

and then i tried to write some code in index.js and checked whether it run or not using command

```
npm run build
```

and it ended up with a bunch of errors like the pic below

[image]

I've been searching a while to resolve this prob but I still cant find out how to solve it.
Plz give me some suggestions to save my day.

I really appreciate your comments!

Comment: You have to `cd` to your project directory

Answer (score -2):

agree with `Andrew Li`.
You also need to write some `run` script in your `package.json` if you want to use npm command

Comment: it seems that your answer isn't clear enough to explain to OP about their current error